# Double limit of Riemann integrals

Tags: real-analysis, limits, riemann-integration, sequence-of-function

Let $\{f_n(x)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a family of infinitely differentiable functions, defined on the entire real line, vanishing outside $[a,b]$. Let $F(x)$ be any function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ with the property that $F$ and all its derivatives are $O(|x|^{-N})$ as $|x|\to\infty$, for every $N$.

By hypothesis, the following limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{x=a}^b f_n(x)F(x)\mathrm{d}x$$

exists for any $F$ of the type specified above.

Is it true or false that $\lim_{|\xi|\to\infty}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{x=a}^b f_n(x)F(x-\xi)\mathrm{d}x\right)=0$ ?

For me it is intuitively true, because $F(x-\xi)$ 'slip away' to infinity as $|\xi|\to\infty$, leaving inside $[a,b]$ a smaller and smaller contribution, but I can't formalize this argument.

Comment: You can probably view the expression in question as a convolution, look at its Fourier transform and look up theorems on how asymptotics influence the Fourier transform of a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We make use of the theorem below.

> **Theorem.** Let $(T_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \subset \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ be a sequence of [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) on $\mathbb{R}$ such that the following conditions hold:
>
> 1. There exists a compact interval $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that each $T_n$ is supported on $K$.
> 2. $(T_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to a linear functional $T$ on $C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R})$ under weak*-topology, that is, $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \langle T_n, \varphi \rangle = \langle T, \varphi \rangle $$ holds for any $\varphi \in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R})$.
>
> Then $T$ is also a distribution on $\mathbb{R}$ that is supported on $K$.
>
> *Proof.* We may regard each $T_n$ as a linear functional on $C^{\infty}(K)$ and we do so. Since $K$ is compact, $C^{\infty}(K)$ is a [Fréchet space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_space) with respect to the topology induced by seminorms $\varphi \mapsto \sup_{x\in K}|\varphi^{(m)}(x)|$, $m\geq 0$. Then a version of uniform boundedness principle ([[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle#Sequences_of_continuous_linear_maps), [[2]](https://pillowmath.github.io/Math%20255A/Lec11.pdf)) shows that the family $(T_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is equicontinuous, hence the pointwise limit $T$ is also continuous. $\square$

Now let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be the sequence of smooth functions as in OP's hypothesis, and let $T$ be the linear functional on $C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R})$ defined by the relation

$$ \langle T, \varphi \rangle = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{a}^{b} f_n(x) \varphi(x) \, \mathrm{d}x $$

for all $\varphi \in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R})$. Then the theorem tells that $T$ is a distribution supported on the compact interval $[a, b]$. Since every compactly supported distribution had finite order, this implies that there exist an integer $k \geq 0$ and a finite constant $C \geq 0$ satisfying

$$ |\langle T, \varphi \rangle| \leq C \sup_{x \in K} |\varphi^{(k)}(x)| $$

for any $\varphi \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$. Consequently, for any $F$ satisfying OP's condition,

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{a}^{b} f_n(x)F(x-\xi) \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \langle T, F(\cdot - \xi) \rangle
= \mathcal{O}\left( \sup_{x \in K} |F^{(k)}(x - \xi)|  \right)
\end{align*}

Now it is easy to check that this vanishes as $|\xi| \to \infty$.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. Could you link me a proof of this theorem, please? In such a way I can study.

Comment: @Nameless, No problem. For example, you can refer to Theorem 8.3.1 of G. Friedlander and M. Joshi. *Introduction to the Theory of Distributions.* Cambridge University Press, 1998.

Comment: It seems to me that the proof is based on an additional hypothesis that I don't have: the continuity. Is that right or am I wrong?
If I am wrong, where can I see that my functional $L(F)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{x=a}^b f_n(x)F(x)\mathrm{d}x$ is continuous?

Comment: @Nameless, That's a good point, and my original argument did not properly verify that the limiting functional is continuous. Now I revamped my answer accordingly.

Comment: I see that for proving continuity there is a lot of extra theory to know. For example, I don't know what a Frechét space is or what seminorms are. I will try to study, meanwhile... thank you very much.

Comment: @Nameless, No problem :) If you already know a bit about Banach spaces (a.k.a. complete normed spaces) and the uniform boundedness principle on then, then you won't have much trouble understanding what a Frechét space is and how UBP generalizes to then. Here is a quick summary: Seminorms are just "degenerate norms", no longer requiring non-zero elements to have positive norm. This means that a single seminorm may not have enough resolution for distinguishing two elements, so we need a family of seminorms to have enough resolution for that. Frechét spaces are defined based on this idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by proving that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{a}^{b} f_n(x)\mathrm d x$$ is finite. For that let
$$h(x) = \begin{cases}
\exp\left({-\frac{1}{\left(e^x - 1\right)^2}}\right) & \text{if $x > 0$}\\
0 & \text{if $x \le 0$}
\end{cases}$$

This $h$ function is infinitly differentiate function such that $$\lim_{x\to \infty} e^x \left(1-h(x)\right) = 0$$

Let $$F(x) = \begin{cases}
1-h(a-x) & \text{if $a < x$}\\
1 & \text{if $a \le x \le b$}\\
1-h(b-x) & \text{if $b < x$}
\end{cases}$$

It is easy to prove that $F$ satisfy the conditions mentionned in the OP so you have that the limit $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_a^bf_n(x)F(x)\mathrm d x$$ exists.